# Finding common value among sub-arrays in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 87
            [1] => 58
            [2] => 85
            [3] => 86
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58
            [1] => 84
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58
        )

)
```

This array above is an example. The actual array is of variable size, but structured like this. Basically, I'd like to run `array_intersect` on each second level array and grab the value (number) that is common between them. In this case, it would be `58`.

I'm not quite sure where to start on this. Any advice?

Comment: When you say the number between them, do you mean a number that's common between all of them? or some of them?

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020483/php-intersecting-multidimensional-array-of-varying-size

Comment: Sorry, number common between all of them. Updated the Array, realized I didn't have a common number in all three in the example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function multi_intersect($arr) {
   $return = array();
   foreach ($arr as $a) {
       foreach ($arr as $b) {
           if ($a === $b) continue;
           $return = array_merge($return, array_intersect($a, $b));
       }
   }
   return array_unique($return);
}
```

Should get you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 58
)
```

The above will work if you have a common number in at least two of the sub-arrays.

*After your edit*:

You can simply use `call_user_func_array` on `array_intersect`, if you want to find numbers that are contained in all sub-arrays:

```
$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't realize it was a simple as your edit, but I actually like the function you posted and may end up using that. Thanks!

Comment: the oneliner is really neat, +1 for beauty

Comment: @John K: If you plan using the function, take the updated one. :) Realized I made a mistake there and that a nested loop was required for that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a mistake in your example and there should be 58 in the [0] element of 'root' array you should just run

`$res = $arr[0];
foreach($arr as $elem)
   $res = array_intersect($res, $elem);`

More general solution (nested arrays):

```
<?php
//$arr -> your multidimensional array
function array_intersect_recursive($arr) {
  $first = true;
  foreach($arr as $elem) {
    if(is_array($elem)) $elem = array_intersect_recursive($arr);
    if($first) { $first = false; $res = $elem; } 
    else $res =  array_intersect($res, $elem);
  } 

}
```

I haven't tested it, but I hope you get the idea.