# array_intersect, but for a sub-arrays of a single array variable

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array that looks like this:

```
$foo = array(
    0 => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
    1 => array('b', 'c', 'd'),
    2 => array('b', 'd', 'f')
)
```

I'll refer to `$foo[0]`, `$foo[1]`, and `$foo[2]` as sub-arrays.

I basically need to perform an `array_intersect()` across all 3 sub-arrays in `$foo`.  The result should be:

```
array('b', 'd')
```

As all three sub-arrays had these values in common.  What is the best way to do this?

Some considerations:

- There will always be at least one sub-array. No upper limit.
- If only one sub-array is provided, it should return that sub-array
- If there aren't any common values in all the sub-arrays, an empty array should be returned
- If this functionality already exists as a PHP function, I will /facepalm

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704166/comparing-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$foo);
```

Note that keys are preserved from $foo[0]

Comment: Clever approach, I like it!  It works fine if `$foo` has at least 2 sub-arrays, but fails if there's just one.  I fixed this by only calling the above if `count($foo) > 1`. If `count($foo) == 1` I just return the only sub-array.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @ColinO'Dell
`$currencies = count($currencies) > 1 ? call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $currencies) : array_shift($currencies);`
**NOTE:** I'm typecasting (array) on $currencies so that array_shift returns `[]`.