# compare more than two array having the same value in same index

Tags: php, arrays

My array is `$worksheets`,

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
        [0] => A. Lange & Sohne 
        [1] => 101.021 
        [2] => 109021) 
[1] => Array ( 
        [0] => A. Lange & Sohne 
        [1] => 101.021 
        [2] => ) 
[3] => Array ( 
        [0] => 
        [1] => 101.021
        [2] => ) 
    )
```

I'm having nested array.For that I use `$total = array_sum(array_map("count", $worksheets));` for counting option.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $total ; $i++) { 
    echo "</br>";

    $sep_ar = $worksheets[$i];
    print_r($sep_ar);

    echo "</br>";
}
```

`$sep_ar` returns the three arrays in separate array since I print it in a `for loop`

Here,I need to check the array index's of each array.

If `Array[0] = A. Lange & Sohne` is in another array I would just like to print it.

How should I do this..!!

Thanks..

Comment: My nested array having `A. Lange & Sohne` value in the same index if it is in the same index of the next nested array I would like to print the value `A. Lange & Sohne`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704166/finding-common-value-among-sub-arrays-in-a-multidimensional-array