# Php - How to find common elements from multidimensional array?

Tags: php

I have city array like this

```
$city = array(
        array(1, 2, 3, 4),
        array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        array(2, 3, 4, 5),
    );
```

I want result like this:

```
$resulted_array=array(2,3,4);
```

I want that without using recursive function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4704211/6797531

Comment: this way i am not getting desired output

Comment: array depth is unlimited , right?

Comment: yes array lenght is unlimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP 5.6 and above, you can directly use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) with the [`...` token](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) (also called *splat operator* in other languages):

```
$city = array(
    array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(2, 3, 4, 5),
);

$inter = array_intersect(...$city);
```

Performance-wise this is much faster than `call_user_func_array()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$resulted_array = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$city);

Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working example for me -

```
<?php

$arr = array(
        array(1, 2, 3, 4),
        array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        array(2, 3, 4, 5),
    );

$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $arr);
print_r($intersect);
?>
```

O/P

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Function was not required. Only above code will work for your requirement.