# PHP check if array value occurs in all multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following multi dimensional PHP array. What I'm trying to do is return only the value which occurs in all of the arrays.

So in the array below the only value which occurs in every array is "2018-02-22", so I want to create a new array with only this value.

I feel like it can't be too difficult, but I just can't get my head around how to do this. If any one can help it would be much appreciated!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-02-22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-02-22
            [1] => 2018-02-21
            [2] => 2018-02-20
            [3] => 2018-02-16
            [4] => 2018-02-14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
           [0] => 2018-02-20
           [1] => 2018-02-19
           [2] => 2018-02-21
           [3] => 2018-02-22
           [4] => 2018-02-14
       )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-02-22
            [1] => 2018-02-12
            [2] => 2018-02-01
        )

)
```

So to clarify the output I'm aiming for is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-02-22
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php - How to find common elements from multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489449/php-how-to-find-common-elements-from-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), to get common value `2018-02-22`.

```
<?php
$dates = [
  ["2018-02-22","2018-02-23"],
  ["2018-02-22","2018-02-24"],
  ["2018-02-22","2018-02-25"],
];
$common = array_shift($dates);
foreach($dates as $key=>$date){
  $common = array_intersect($common, $date);  
}
print_r($common);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/961434)

Output is :

```
Array (
    [0] => 2018-02-22 
)
```