# Find Common most values in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the common values as an array from a multidimensional Array.

Here is my array look likes :

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000
        [1] => 001
        [2] => 002
        [3] => 003
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000
        [1] => 001
        [2] => 002
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000
        [1] => 001
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000
        [1] => 001
        [2] => 002
        [3] => 003
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000
        [1] => 001
        [2] => 002
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000
        [1] => 001
    )
   )
```

I need the result as like this. My need is to find the most common values in the array, that means in the array the value 000 is coming most, that should be in first in output array like that the next value is 001 is most.

I referred this :

> [Finding common value among sub-arrays in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704166/finding-common-value-among-sub-arrays-in-a-multidimensional-array)

The problem I didn't get the least one is not getting in the final array.

> output needed

```
Array
(
    [0] => 000
    [1] => 001
    [2] => 002
    [3] => 003
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a `foreach` and use the array values as the key and increment each times it matches.

At the end sort the keys using [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) and return the keys using [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) :

```
$arrays = [
    ['000', '001', '002', '003'],
    ['000', '001', '002'],
    ['000', '001'],
    ['000', '001', '002', '003'],
    ['000', '001', '002'],
    ['000', '001'],
];

$result = [];

foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (!array_key_exists($a, $result)) {
            $result[$a] = 1;
            continue;
        }
        $result[$a] += 1;
    }
}
ksort($result);
print_r(array_keys($result));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/SYKOY)

Ouput

```
Array
(
    [0] => 000
    [1] => 001
    [2] => 002
    [3] => 003
)
```