# How do you find most common array in multidimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to find the most common (most occurring) array in a multidimensional array. Not the most common values like this post - [Find Common most values in multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440351/find-common-most-values-in-multidimensional-array-in-php) - but rather the most common combination.

For example, if I have the following:

```
$a1=array(
    array('704322062'),
    array('678073776', '704322062'),
    array('678073776', '704322062'),
    array('704322064'),
    array('704322062'),
    array('678073776'),
    array('678073776', '704322062')
);
```

I want to be able to detect that the array that occurs most often is `array('678073776', '704322062')` not that the string `'704322062'` is most common.

I've tried using array_intersect but couldn't get it working for this scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`array_count_values` only works with scalar values, not when the items are arrays themselves. But we can still use that function, if we transform your arrays into strings first - by encoding them as JSON.

```
// fill temp array with items encoded as JSON
$temp = [];
foreach($a1 as $item) {
  $temp[] = json_encode($item);
}

// count how many times each of those values occurs
$value_counts = array_count_values($temp);
// sort by number of occurrence, while preserving the keys
ksort($value_counts);

// pick the first key from the temp array
$first = array_key_first($value_counts);
```

This will get you `["678073776","704322062"]` in $first now - you can `json_decode` it again, if you want your “original” array.

Note that this does not take into account, that two arrays could occur the same amount of times - then it will just pick the “random” first one of those. If you need to handle that case as well somehow, then you can determine the maximum value in $temp first, and then filter it by that value, so that only those keys of the corresponding arrays will be left.

Comment: You don't address the issue that `array('678073776', '704322062')` could be equal to `array('704322062', '678073776')`. The question doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware good point – should that also be a requirement, then `$item` could be sorted first, before it gets encoded as JSON and added to the temp array.

Comment: Thanks so much - this has worked perfectly @CBroe And I just dropped in a sort on `$item` to @KIKOSoftware's point. Thank you both!