# how to intersect 2 multidimensional array into third multimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have 2 arryas and i want them to intersect and store the finding matches into third array with values from first array and second array.
the first array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 10640
            [2] => 1041-0567041700116
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46
            [1] => 10640
            [2] => 1041-0567041700318
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 207
            [1] => 10645
            [2] => 03320103000052
        )
```

and the second array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03320103000052
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10013800805001
            [1] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1090-0360141758201
            [1] => 3
        )
```

the out put should be:

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 207                     =>value from first array
                [1] => 10645                   =>value from first array
                [2] => 03320103000052          =>value from first and second array (this is what i need to compare)
                [3] => 0                       =>value from second array
            )
```

this is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020483/intersecting-multidimensional-array-of-varying-size)

but i have problems to store data into multidimensional array

thanks in forward for any suggestions and help

Comment: I don't understand how 207, 10645, 03320103000052 and 0 are grouped together. how do they intersect?

Comment: i intersect 2 arrays. if matches found (matching value is 03320103000052) and then i want to take the other values from first and second array into new array

Comment: This seems somewhat overcomplicated to be practically applied ... how are you using all of this?

Comment: the first array is from database and the second array is from another database as csv export. when i intersect into new array i would be able to update the new data in first database

Comment: And you dropped all the column names? Those would be very useful in this case, otherwise the merge will be horribly expensive.

Comment: yes i droped the column names because i don't need them and i know what the data means. after all i will comment my code so i can always get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with only two foreach loops and one if statement:

```
$combined = array();
foreach ($array1 as $a) {
    foreach ($array2 as $b) {
        if ($a[2] == $b[0]) {
            $combined[] = array($a[0], $a[1], $a[2], $b[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the test I set up to try this:

```
<?php
$array1 = array();
$array1[] = array('45', '10640', '1041-0567041700116');
$array1[] = array('46', '10640', '1041-0567041700318');
$array1[] = array('207', '10645', '03320103000052');

$array2 = array();
$array2[] = array('03320103000052', '0');
$array2[] = array('10013800805001', '12');
$array2[] = array('1090-0360141758201', '3');


$combined = array();
foreach ($array1 as $a) {
    foreach ($array2 as $b) {
        if ($a[2] == $b[0]) {
            $combined[] = array($a[0], $a[1], $a[2], $b[1]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($combined);
?>
```

Comment: your answer fails if the sub-array in `$b` has more or less than 2 values

Comment: also what if `a[1] == b[1]` ? you cannot simply say that only `a[2]` will only be equal to `b[1]`

Comment: my question is anwsered. guys, you rock. because both codes are working in my case i cannot give to both the check mark and i am very dissapointed about this so i will leave it blank

Comment: Why the mark down if this solves the users programming question? The user didn't ask for a 4 loop solution to cover a bunch of different might happen scenarios.

Comment: comment to krishna: a[2] will be always the same as b[0] and the b[1] doesnt matter. the comparison of a[1] == b[1] also doesnt matter. only the comparison of $a[2] == $b[0] does matter and the rest of data needed to be combined

Comment: @KevBot one advice this kind writing program `(simply hardcorded)` is never going to help anyone

Comment: i need this just once. when it will be finished i will never touch this again because it will be in cron job of server. make it and leave it.

Comment: @user2989040 I made a slight modification to the IF statement based on those last few comments you made. It will ensure the correct comparison every time.