# How to get the intersection of an array of multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of multidimentional arrays.  Each array represents a result set from a search.  I am having trying to figure out how to filter this set of data to only include arrays that are present in each array.

Note: The index's shown below each represent multidimentional arrays.  Each array has a deeply nested `Id` key that can be used for comparison.

The `Id` is located at:

`$reference_variable['data']['Id'][0]`

For example,

```
array(
    array([0], [19], [21], [148]),
    array([2], [21], [32], [44], [432], [549]),
    array([13], [21], [148])
)
```

Should return:

```
array(
    [21]
)
```

and:

```
array(
    array([0], [12], [15]),
    array([2], [21], [32], [44], [432], [549]),
    array([13], [21], [148])
)
```

Should return:

```
array(
    []
)
```

What is the best way to handle this?  [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) does not work well with multidimensional arrays.

I've already tried storing all `Id`s in an array, and using `array_count_values` to find duplicate `Id`s, and then use `array_filter` to compare if the `Id` of the current array was equal to any of the duplicate `Id`'s.

But that turned out to be totally wrong since this method would allow:

```
array(
    array([0], [19], [21], [148]),
    array([2], [21], [32], [44], [432], [549]),
    array([13], [21], [148])
)
```

To return:

```
array(
    [21, 148]
)
```

Which is not the intersection of all arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer in my case:

```
$params = array_merge($array_of_arrays, array('array_compare'));

$intersection = call_user_func_array('array_uintersect', $params);

function array_compare($a1, $a2) 
{
    if ($a1 === $a2) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($a1 > $a2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020654/1911755

Answer (score 0):

Just store the indexes of the first array in an array.  Check for matching indexes on the second array and store those in a second array A2.  Check for matches between the second stored array ( A2 ) and the third array.  Call it A3 for consistency ( A3 ).  This is your answer.

Maybe 10-20 lines of code.